# converging multiple admin login scripts into one

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I have a few scripts all linked to the same SQL database, but each one has its own admin.php

I have created links to the other admin.php(s) in the one I would consider the main admin panel.

as it is the same user name and ID how can I get the links to fill and submit the login details so I only have to login on the first admin panel and not each time a click a link to a new one

any help appreciated

Comment: how does your login system work? if you have a good login system this should not be a problem.

Comment: I use sitelok to sing into the main site and vanilla forum, but the blog and guestbook back end both have there own sign in admin, as its the same username for all, I am wondering if I can either remove the need to sign in, or to populate the information and send it it as I arrive on the page which would lead to a refrsh and direct into the admin functions

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to store some kind of authentication information in session data. Each time you access a script, it will check the session variables for some kind of security token. If it's there, it can use that to determine who has logged-in.

At the top of each PHP script (before you've output any HTML), include a call to [`session_start()`](http://www.php.net/session_start). This will enable session information. You can then read/write elements in the [`$_SESSION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) superglobal array.

If you want the browser to remember the login for subsequent visits, you could also use cookie data. Just be aware that cookies are not particularly secure, so don't store usernames and passwords in them directly. Use some a unique encrypted/hashed token instead.

Comment: I have the session start, but its not quite what I was asking.

Comment: sitelok can be added to all the admin.phps I have meaning that they can only be accessed if signed in through sitelok, but I want to remove the need for the other sign ins, can I make the sign ins contain the sign data and set an auto refresh or can I remove the need for the other sign ins altogether seeing as they all access the same database?

Comment: Why can't you use session data to do that? Are the other sign-ins on a different server?

Comment: they are all on the same server, I could do that, once I learn how, never really learned this side of things, until now, I am assuming each admin file uses its own session or its own cookie to identify my login as logining into one does not log me into another, which is what I want it to do, thus removing the need to login multiple times, be it by sending session data or manually

Comment: guess I am looking for a hint as to where to begin such a task, is there a standard piece of code that would identify me, or would it be unique to each programmer in which case its going to be a long slog finding it

Comment: As with most programming tasks, the code will depend on your specific situation. Session data is a very common part of PHP though, so there are lots of tutorials online which should help you.